# Could not install : Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nuget

I want to download and parse the JSON in my Windows Phone project, so I decided to download `newtonsoft.json` library via Nuget in Visual Studios, but I'm receiving the following:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
 + Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Try updating NuGet to the latest version and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum already tested but nothing changes !!!!

Comment: @user2068754 How did you test it? Update your question with a relevant code example that you attempted. Show us how its not working.

Comment: @msm8bball im alredy downloaded source code of Newtonsoft.Json from codeplex but i dont know how can i add a refrence to that resource the zip file im downloaded (Json 6.0.1) tree is :                         Bin , Source  |   Bin - > net2 , net3 , ... net45 , portable , portable 40 , winRT |    Source - > Build , Doc , Source , Tools

Comment: @msm8bball to be fair, I've used `Newtonsoft.Json` several times in WP8 projects without having to do this.

Comment: +1 dont know why this question is getting downvoted. Having the very same problems, and would appreciate the help. None of the above comments have been particularly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Download the component (aka DLL) from here: http://james.newtonking.com/json

**Note:** Make sure to delete any previous Nuget traces of the old Newtonsoft component you had. Just to make sure things are clear before you attempt to do this.

- Once downloaded, extract the contents of the compressed file to a folder.
- You will see two directories, `Bin` and `Source`. The one that you
  care about is the `Bin` directory.
- You will find additional directories within `Bin`, pick the one that corresponds to your framework of choice. .NET 3.5? 4.0? RT?
- You will find the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` copy this over to your project's `bin` directory located inside the project's `Debug` folder.
- Open your project in Visual Studio, right click on the `References Folder` under your project name and select `Add Reference`
- Click `Browse` and find the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, Hit Apply if necessary and then OK.

Answer (score 0):

You've two options. The second one is a little more brute force.

Run VS 2013 in admin mode, then in BUILD, run a Clean, *helps to-- ensure your config manager has the build option set to build and copy everytime. The will force it remove stale dll's to put new ones in*

option 1:

1. Uninstall the package from the package manager and re-install. 
   Before re-install open up the packages manifest file (XML file) to
   verify it was uninstalled.
2. If not delete the references manually.
3. Then go to the 2 folders where the packages, DLL's are installed. /Bin and
   /packages and delete the Newton.JSON DLL and the Newton.JSON folder
   Now reinstall

Option 2:

- Go directly to step 2. VS 2013 will complain at first, about not finding a folder to delete. But will work.

  PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json done

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the source package being incorrect, please see my answer on this question [Package error question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296006/unable-to-install-newtonsoft-json/44944552#44944552)