# Unable to install Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to install Newtonsoft Json (with the package manager console) so that I can use it in my C# console app, but I get this error:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Newtonsoft.Json'
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: what's your package source in the package manager console?

Comment: Do any nuget packages work? What is the Package Source selected?

Comment: I have the same problem - dod you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, you have to have the package source set to .NET, which is not set by default

Answer (score 1):

I might be just be late to answer, but this is usually caused by the incorrect package source, different packages come from different sources, for example angularJS.core packages comes from nuget.org source so if you search it and you have Microsoft and .NET set as your source, then you wont be able to find it.

To attempt to answer your question, please select the change the source on your your PM console(see attached screenshot) [image], you might also want to make sure that you point to the correct project(attached screenshot will also guide you on that regard). Or even better just select "All" on your source and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to install it from Package manager UI. Right click in your solution/project and select `manage nuget package`. In the presented UI search for `newtonsoft.json` and install accordingly.

Also make sure your project don't already have it installed. In your project find the file name `package.config` and search for an entry named `json.net`. If present, delete that line, save the file and then try re-installing again.

Comment: @MattyAB, make sure you already haven't installed the package and if so then delete all references and try re-installing the package.

Comment: @MattyAB: did you choose a package source? i cannot see one selected in your screenshot

Comment: @MattyAB Could you please check if there is some NuGet package source entry in Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources. If not add them from nuget.org . 
NuGet feed v3 (VS 2015 / NuGet v3.x): https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
NuGet feed v2 (VS 2013 and earlier / NuGet 2.x): https://www.nuget.org/api/v2

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c47593c3-c755-4701-9280-1c25f5c8b348/installpackage-unable-to-find-package-newtonsoftjson), maybe it can help you. Basically, do this:

First of all, if you have any old version of *Newtonsoft.Json*, I recommend uninstalling it. For this you can use the *NuGet Package Manager for Solution* (in *Tools*)

Then, in the *Package Manager Settings* add a new package source with name **nuget.org** and source **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**

Finally, using the *NuGet Package Manager Console*, install the latest version of *Newtonsoft.Json* (the one shown at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). For example, in my case the latest version is 13.0.1, so I ran the following command in the PM console:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 13.0.1
```

That's all.